# How to access a class within a new nuget package that is already installed in another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I have two projects P1 and P2 in my solution.
I created a private nuget package which I installed in project P1.

(manage nuget package - installing for folder location where the nuget package physically exist).

P1 project reference is also added in project P2.
The classes/methods inside nuget package is needed in project P2 as well...

Installing the nuget package again in project P2 works fine without any issue.
But everytime when I update my private nuget package, I need to re-install the nuget package in both these projects.

I want to reference the class/methods of nuget package in P2 using the 'P1 Project Reference' which already exist. So that when nuget package is updated, I need to re-install in only one project(P1).

Is it possible to achieve this...

Thanks for any help.

Priya.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If P1 generates a nuget package, then msbuild will convert the project reference to a package reference during publishing. Your P1 has another PackageReference, these classes should already be available in P2 too

Comment: P1 is refered in P2 as project reference and not nuget package.....using clause in P2, doesnt allow to refer the namespace in nuget package....

Comment: You need to upgrade the nuget package at the solution level so that the new version will be upgraded to all the projects. You can not use the classes of Nuget package if it is not directly referenced in the project.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/cw7oQpsXmupj.png

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/7KPCNJO2iGhS.png

Comment: So shld manage nuget package at solution level and upgrade the nuget package in all projects which uses it....

Comment: When you open Manage Nuget Package For Solutions and select the nuget package, it will show all the projects which are using it. You can select the project(s) and upgrade for them.